# ETL on GCP for ML

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl

I am new to GCP My requirement is as follow:

Wanted to Extract more than one table from BigQuery , Transform the data and Save it on Google cloud storage in tsv format for ML model predictions . I wanted to this in Python code so that i will have more control over it and i can schedule it.
Can you suggest best methods to do it or any other alternative ?

i didnt find any resource explaining above problem most of the articles are on ETL of loading external data into BigQuery but my data is already in BigQuery i just need to Transform it and save it somewhere(GCS)

Comment: Can you transform the data with a SQL statement before the storage in Cloud Storage? And what's the volume of data? Must you have only one file as output, or multiple with the same prefix is possible?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i cant simply transform data with SQL , i will have to go through python code only for transformations

Answer (score 1):

If you can perform all your transformation is SQL, I strongly recommend to avoid Python for data transformation and handling, only for API calls (and you can even avoid Python Code if you use product like [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) or [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows)).

For your export, use the [BigQuery Export statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement), and set the field_delimiter to `\t`. If you have less than 1Gb of data, you can use a GCS URI without wildcard `*`. Else a wildcard will be mandatory, and you will have several output files.

If it's an issue, you can reuse code sample that I shared in [one of my articles](https://medium.com/google-cloud/get-a-single-one-csv-file-with-bigquery-export-956d2a147886) -> That article is a BigQuery export, you can almost reuse all the code in it